4 motion sensors to cover 2 lights
I have a hallway where 4 switches control 2 lights.  I want to switch out all 4 switches with motion sensors so what ever room you leave it will kick on the hallway lights.  I am trying to figure out what switches I need to make the circuit work.  I believe I will need a 3 way switch on the ends and 4 way switches in the middle, but I can't seem to find 4 way motion switches or anything that will make the connection work.

I don't use any, so far, but my vague understanding is that most "smart switches" which some motion sensors fall under don't use the traditional 3-way/4-way setup - they communicate among themselves using signals on the power lines to tell the one that actually switches the lights to do that, but without the travelers and need for 4 ways that the dumb switch method calls for. In some cases this seems to call for one special switch that does the switching and a bunch of satellite switches that just tell it to switch, which can't switch anything without the special one they talk to.

What wires are available at the various boxes?

I haven't opened up the switches yet to see what wires are running in each box.  I was trying to figure out what switches I will need to purchase before I dive into the boxes.

@Jordan we need to know which wires are in the boxes to determine what's practical to do/buy here

Motion sensors shouldn't use the 3/4-way switches.  Because motion on any one should turn the circuit on.  3/4-way switches turn the lights when an odd number of switches triggered.

This question is similar to: 3 Motion Sensors to 1 Light Circuit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can make this work with four motion sensors eliminating all existing switches, plus optionally having a master system enable/disable switch and a master "all on" switch. This previous post explains how: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/301211/79373
